# How is this simplification done?

Tags: propositional-calculus

The models of the formula $p \rightarrow \neg(q \rightarrow r)$ are $V_{2}, V_{5}, V_{6}, V_{7}, V_{8}$. In disjunctive normal form this would be:

$(p \wedge q \wedge \neg r) \vee (\neg p \wedge q \wedge r) \vee (\neg p \wedge q \wedge \neg r) \vee (\neg p \wedge \neg q \wedge r) \vee (\neg p \wedge \neg q \wedge \neg r)$

In the book it says that this formula can be simplified to $(p \wedge q \wedge \neg r) \vee \neg p$. It says that the disjunction of the last four conjunctions is equivalent with $\neg p$.

I would like to know how this simplification is done in the most simplest of terms, since the book doesn't mention anything about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A literal consists of a lower case letter or its negation.  Each conjunction here consists of three literals from the set of literals {p, ¬p, q, ¬q, r, ¬r} where no letter appears twice in a conjunction.  Now, suppose that we have a conjunction with ¬p as the first literal.  What are the other possibilities for the other two literals?  Well, the possibilities correspond to pairs (q, r), (q, ¬r), (¬q, r), (¬q, ¬r).  Consequently, every possibility for "¬p" gets covered by the last four conjunctions cover all cases where "¬p" holds true.  Thus, if any of the last 4 cases, then ¬p holds true.

Perhaps a better way to think about it, let's write the truth table out here:

```
p   q   r   F(p, q, r)
0   0   0   1   
0   0   1   1
0   1   0   1
0   1   1   1
1   0   0   0
1   0   1   0
1   1   0   1
1   1   1   0
```

If p, q, and r are false, then ¬p, ¬q, and ¬r are true.  Thus (¬p$\land$¬q$\land$¬r) corresponds to the first row above.  (¬p$\land$¬q$\land$r) corresponds to the second row above and so.  The last four conjunctions of the formula in the post correspond to the 1st 4 rows above.  This consists of the only time that ¬p holds true.  Equivalently, if ¬p holds true, then a disjunction of the 4 conjunctions will hold true.  Consequently, we can replace such a disjunction of conjunctions by ¬p.

Actually, we could further simplify the formula to [¬p$\lor$(q$\land$$\lnot$r)].

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely correct on the further simplification, this was in the same answer. I figured that if I could get an answer for the first simplification, I'd be able to figure out the second. You beat me to it though! And, of course, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** $(a \wedge b) \vee (a \wedge c) \equiv a \wedge (b \vee c)$

Also, a satisfiable expression $f$ has some satisfying assignment $y_1 \dots y_n$. Given any assignment $x_1 \dots x_n$ we have map $x_i = y_i$ or $\neg x_i = y_i$. Therefore if we fix any assignment $x_i$ and try all possible ways to negate its variables, we will run into one that satisfies $f$.

Comment: I get what you're trying to say, but I still can't frame it. E.g.: $\neg p \vee (p \wedge q \wedge \neg r)$ would be $(\neg p \vee p) \wedge (\neg p \vee q) \wedge (\neg p \vee \neg r)$. Otherwise, removing $\neg p$ from the last 4 disjunctions, what happens to the $\neg q$'s, $q$'s, $\neg r$'s, $r$'s$ in that formula?

Comment: I see your edited post, thanks for your effort. But I do not understand what you are talking about.

Comment: @GarthMarenghi, $f(x, y) = x \wedge y$ is satisfiable at $f(1, 1)$. What you have after moving $\neg p$ is $f(x, y) \vee f(\neg x, y) \vee f(x, \neg y) \vee f(\neg x, \neg y)$. Those are all the possible ways to put $\neg$ before $x$ and $y$. No matter what $x, y$ you start with, one of the terms will evaluate to $f(1, 1)$. Hence what you have is a tautology.